# Effective algorithms to find k clique communities

Tags: python, networkx

I am running `k_cliques_communities` from networkX on my network data, which has ~600 nodes and ~10,000 edges, and I run into memory error. The same code can be applied to a similar network which has ~600 nodes and ~9000 edges without errors. 
The number of nodes and edges are quite the same but the first encounter a memory error.

What might cause this issue and how can I solve it? Is it because of the effectiveness?

Comment: get more memory?

Comment: rather than the number of nodes and edges, it may be the number of cliques found that is causing the memory error. you don't happen to run the code on the same dataset, do you?

Comment: The number of cliques is set equals 3 for all of them.

Comment: When you say they are similar networks, can you give us an estimate of how many cliques you expect it to find in each of them?  If you try a large enough value of k, probably you won't get an error.  Can you do that and then start reducing k until you get an error?  Then tell us what you get for both networks for values of k a bit above the value giving the error?  I suspect you'll see a big difference between the two networks.